# How to insert where not exists

Tags: mysql, sql

To prevent data duplication, I tried to use the 'where not exists' syntax.

I can't set that column to a unique value. This only necessary in certain situations. Duplicate data is sometimes possible.

Here's my table `test` (`id`: Auto increment)

| id | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |

I tried this:

```sql
insert into test (val1, val2) 
select 4, 4 from test
where not exists 
(select * from test 
where val1 = 4 and val2 = 4 
limit 1);
```

Here's what I actually got:

| id | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 4 | 4 |
| 6 | 4 | 4 |

Here's the result I was expecting:

| id | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 |

And when I run the same query after that, the insertion didn't happen as I intended. However, if there is no duplicate data, only one row should be entered.

What should I do?

Comment: You're nesting three queries. Debug. Test each tier individually and see which one isn't returning what you think it should be returning.

Comment: You said `id` is auto-increment, but you have `4` three times in your results

Comment: @rafalon makes a good point. Amend the question with the CREATE TABLE statement, if you can.

Comment: I would suggest you create a noncluster index e.g.:  CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UQ_test_val1_val2 ON test (val1, val2);

Comment: Sorry. It was just my mistake..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wanted to do here is to not select from any table (or use `dual` if you do want a `FROM` clause:

```sql
INSERT INTO test (val1, val2) 
SELECT 4, 4
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM test
    WHERE val1 = 4 AND val2 = 4
);
```

Your current query will insert the tuple `(4, 4)` for *every* record in the `test` table, which isn't the behavior you want.

Comment: It works. I think I used it without understanding the syntax properly..